# Codeception not accepting localhost url

Tags: php, laravel, codeception

I'm running Codeception against a Laravel Homestead vagrant instance. PHP version 5.5.12, Laravel 4.*. Codeception version 2.0.0.

I can access the site via Chrome using localhost:8000, 127.0.0.1:8000, or mysite.app:8000. The site is also deployed remotely on an AWS server, which has no domain name but a public IP address which works fine when viewed via Chrome.

I can also curl all of these urls locally just fine.

I've followed the setup procedure indicated here: http://codeception.com/quickstart

Every step but the very last one works fine.

My test, **WelcomeCert.php**:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('see the landing page');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('Welcome');
```

**acceptance_suite.yml**:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - AcceptanceHelper
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
```

The console output when I execute **codecept run**:

```
1) Failed to see the landing page in WelcomeCept.php (/Users/andrew/code/site/tests/acceptance/WelcomeCept.php)
Sorry, I couldn't am on page "/":
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

Scenario Steps:
1. I am on page "/"

#1  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/SetCookie.php:250
#2  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/SetCookie.php:84
#3  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/SetCookie.php:70
#4  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/CookieJar.php:200
#5  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Subscriber/Cookie.php:57
#6  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Event/Emitter.php:105
#7  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Event/RequestEvents.php:75
#8  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Adapter/Curl/CurlAdapter.php:94
#9  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Adapter/StreamingProxyAdapter.php:34
#10 /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:186
#1  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/SetCookie.php:250
#2  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/SetCookie.php:84
#3  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/SetCookie.php:70
#4  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Cookie/CookieJar.php:200
#5  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Subscriber/Cookie.php:57
#6  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Event/Emitter.php:105
#7  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Event/RequestEvents.php:75
#8  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Adapter/Curl/CurlAdapter.php:94
#9  /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Adapter/StreamingProxyAdapter.php:34
#10 /Users/andrew/code/site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:186

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I get the same error when I try to access http://www.google.com or http://www.github.com.

Comment: It looks like you have not set the timezone setting in php.ini on your local machine. See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my comment as an answer.

It looks like you have not set the timezone setting in php.ini on your local machine. See php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.